# Prove that there exists exactly 1 solution to $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2}$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Prove that there exists exactly 1 solution to $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2}$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I've been looking around for this problem, but I haven't found it here so I asked. What the title says. Thank you in advance for anyone who takes their time to help me :)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts (I think if you just write down what this is asking, it will be obvious to you).

Comment: Hint : There are only two possible solutions , $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Oh wait, I've misunderstood the question completely. I thought that I had to get the same solution for x regardless of the value of a... good to know I've spent 2 hrs on this in vain haha

Answer (score 2):

Note $x^2\equiv x\pmod{2}$ so $x\equiv a \pmod{2}$ is the only solution.

Comment: `\pmod{a}` produces a regular space, parentheses, and the roman typeface for `mod`. For the version without parentheses, use `\bmod` to get just the `mod` with regular spaces before and after. To remember, `\pmod` is " **p**arentheses mod", and `\bmod` is " **b**inary mod".